# Adding coupon to products with unit price limit

Tags: magento-1.9

I am new to Magento. I wish to add a discount coupon to products with unit price more than $20.00. Please help me in creating the condition for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a product attribute for all products with a unit price over $20.00 (make sure it can be used in promo rule conditions) and then use that product attribute in the shopping cart rule actions.